# Proving the Convergence: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\sqrt{n + r} - \sqrt{n})$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm having trouble proving the convergence for this series using real analysis methods: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$$where for $r > 0$ a positive real number,$$a_n = \sqrt{n + r} - \sqrt{n}$$

---

My approach so far has been to use the ratio test for $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}$, which gives me the fraction $\frac{\sqrt{k + 1 + r} - \sqrt{k + 1}}{\sqrt{k + r} - \sqrt{k}}$. I multiply the top and bottom by the denominators conjugate, which conveniently leaves just $r$ on the bottom, but it leaves a pretty gross numerator: $$\frac{\sqrt{k^2 + 2kr + k  + r^2 + r} + \sqrt{k^2 + kr + k} - \sqrt{k^2 + k + k + r} - \sqrt{k^2 + k}}{r}$$

At this point, a high school calculus style analysis would be content with me just saying that the limit of this is zero based on the degrees of the terms. But I'm totally lost on how I should prove that the limit for this is $0$ based on the $\epsilon$ definition for limits.

---

Is there some sort of algebraic manipulation that we can do here to make the $\epsilon$ inequality for the limit definition turn out nicely? Alternatively, is there some other method I should be trying to use?

Thank you for your time and help:)

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt {n + r}  - \sqrt n  = \frac{r}{{\sqrt {n + r}  + \sqrt n }}$.

Comment: Are you really sure the sum converges? The ration test is the necessary condition not sufficient. I think the sum is divergent.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I'm always struck by identities like this. Deriving useful ones without reference seems like a tough skill to train.

Comment: @K.K.McDonald The graph of $a_n$ itself converges to 0, so I figured that this means that the series satisfies the Cauchy criterion for sums, since summations starting near the 'tail' of the series would be less than $\epsilon$. Am I mistaken in believing this?

Comment: Please notice that if $n>\frac{1}{r-2}$ assuming $r>2$ then $\sqrt{n+r}-\sqrt{n}>\frac{1}{n}$ which is harmonic series and divergent. I used MATLAB for calculating sum and I'm sure it grows boundless when you increase $n$. For example $r=5$ and $n=1:10^4$

Comment: That $a_n$ itself converges to $0$ is *not* the Cauchy criterion. It only means that, for each $\epsilon>0$, for some $N$, for each $n\geq N$, $\lvert a_n\rvert<\epsilon$.  The Cauchy criterion starts out similar, but it ends with $\lvert\sum_{k=n}^{m}\rvert<\epsilon$ for each $m\geq n$, a much stronger statement. Thus it is a theorem (the $n$th-Term Test for divergence) that *if* $\sum_{n=i}^\infty a_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, but the converse does *not* hold.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks so much to all of you! It means a lot that you're willing to help a confused stranger like me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a divergent series. One has
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {(\sqrt {n + r}  - \sqrt n )}  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{r}{{\sqrt {n + r}  + \sqrt n }}}  > \frac{r}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {n + r} }}}  > \frac{r}{{2\sqrt {1+r} }}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{\sqrt n }}} ,
$$
and the last series is obviously divergent.

Comment: Thanks for the help! One question: I don't follow how $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{r}{\sqrt{n+r} + \sqrt{n}} > \frac{r}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+r}}$$ Isn't it the case that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+r} + \sqrt{n}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+r}}$? If so, why would dividing the second series by 2 change anything?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it!

Answer (score 1):

Let $n >n_0 >r$ ($n_0$ exists, Archimedean principle)

$a_n=\dfrac{r}{\sqrt{n+r}+√n}>$

$\dfrac{r}{2\sqrt{n+r}}>\dfrac{r}{2\sqrt{n+n}}=$

$\dfrac{r}{2√2√n}= \dfrac{r}{2√2}\dfrac{1}{√n}$.

$\sum a_n$ diverges (comparison test), since $\sum \dfrac{1}{√n}$ diverges

Comment: Thanks! What was the purpose of $n_0$ here? Is it just a formality to show that there *can* be something greater than $r$?

Comment: Barbaric.A pleasure. In proves like this usually one writes: For $n >r$(real>0), without $n_0$. Actually given $r >0$, the Archimedean principle assures a $n_0 >r$(you can look it up).Then for all $n >n_0$ we have $n>r$. You can leave it($n_0$) out here , and just say: For $n>r$. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Since $r>0$ thus $\sqrt{n+r}-\sqrt{n}>0$. Let's find the $n$ for which $\sqrt{n+r}-\sqrt{n}>\frac{\alpha}{n}$ where $\alpha>0$ is some positive constant. Therefore

$$n+r+n-2\sqrt{n(n+r)}>\left( \frac{\alpha}{n} \right)^2\Rightarrow 2n+r-\left( \frac{\alpha}{n} \right)^2>2\sqrt{n(n+r)} \\ \Rightarrow 4n^2+r^2+\left( \frac{\alpha}{n} \right)^4+4nr-2r\left( \frac{\alpha}{n} \right)^2-4n\left( \frac{\alpha}{n} \right)^2>4n^2+4nr\\ \Rightarrow \left( r-\left( \frac{\alpha}{n} \right)^2 \right)^2>\frac{4\alpha^2}{n}\Rightarrow r>\left( \frac{\alpha}{n} \right)^2+\frac{2\alpha}{\sqrt{n}}$$

For large $n$ this is inevitable and the series is comparable to harmonic series which diverges. For example if we assume $n$ is large enough such that $\left( \frac{\alpha}{n} \right)<\left( \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{n}} \right)$ (i.e. $n>1$) then

$$r+1>\left( \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{n}}+1 \right)^2\Rightarrow \sqrt{r+1}>\left( \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{n}} +1\right)\Rightarrow \sqrt{n}>\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{r+1}-1}$$

Thus if $n>\left(\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{r+1}-1}\right)^2$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n>\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha}{n},\alpha>0$

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to prove that the series diverges.

For natural $r$, the series telescopes, leaving you  with

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n+r}+\sqrt{n+r-1}+\cdots\sqrt{n+1}-f(r).$$

For non-natural $r$, you can use squeezing between the series for two naturals.